# Where can I find a free/opensource Delphi multimedia component?

Tags: delphi, components, multimedia, vlc, codec

I was in a project where I must be able to play almost audio/video files (format).

#### The requirements:

#### Video:

- .dat (vcd & svcd)
- .vob (dvd)
- .rmvb (real media)
- .mp4 (mpeg4/x264/h264)
- .wmv/.asf (windows media)
- .avi (xvid/divx/mpeg2,etc...)
- .mkv (matroska, optional)

  #### Audio:
- .mp3 (you probably know this)
- .ogg (vorbis)
- .wma (windows media)
- .wav (wave)

I already have all of the above codecs installed and working perfect on my system (tried it with WMP 10, Media Player Classic Home Cinema, VLC & Zoom Player).

And I have already tried the basic TMediaPlayer but can't work on other beside .avi for video, then i grab DSPack but it can't play .avi (xvid/divx) nor .mkv, i grab VLC but it's only gave me more headache because it was only ActiveX wrapper (no pure vcl component).

Can someone suggest another component? Free or open source would be preferred.

Edit:
I already solve issue with DSPack, it looks like I have to use always FDDShow for video playing using DSPack.

Comment: changed your title into a form that is more wiki-compatible since you've already found what you needed!

Comment: ok thanks, i'm really new here

Comment: So, did you manage to open divx files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DSPack was going to be my suggestion. I'm not sure what problems you had with DivX - I've used the free DivX codec with a DSPack-based program for years. FFDShow looks like a promising solution, too, although I've experienced problems with the quality of playback (tearing, low frame rates, instability when playing for a long periond, etc.) for some types of files. The video hardware and drivers are also very important, and unless you're supplying the complete hardware, software and image package, the users of your program may run into different problems in terms of the subjective acceptability (to them) of the playback. Keep that in mind - codec versions are important, driver versions are crucial, and some hardware just doesn't work right, no matter what the manufacturer says.

Comment: yes i already solve the problem, looks like i must use "Always Use FFDShow" setting for program i created

btw thanks for the answer

Answer (score 5):

You can import the WMP 10 ActiveX control (Component->Import Component menu item), and then embed WMP into your application.

Since it's part of the operating system, can't get any more free than that; if you can run your Delphi app, the OS is there. :-)

Comment: It is part of OS... For now... Maybe... Until some screaming idiots blame Microsoft (because they want to sell their own spyware (yes, we hate you RealPlayer))